# Detecting squares in an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I found this square detection code online and I'm trying to understand it, does anyone understand what the line at the end does? it states: "gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;"

Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;

```
// down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));
pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
vector<vector<Point> > contours;

// find squares in every color plane of the image
for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
{
    int ch[] = {c, 0};
    mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

    // try several threshold levels
    for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ )
    {
        // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
        // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
        if( l == 0 )
        {
            // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
            // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
            Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
            // dilate canny output to remove potential
            // holes between edge segments
            dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
        }
        else
        {
            // apply threshold if l!=0:
            // tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
            gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This code snipped is a part of the git repository `CVSquares`. From experience, I know that this library does not work well on real images though works good in computer generated images. Plus this method of detection on RGB without converting to grayscale is very computationally expensive.

Anyways the line of code you are asking about is basically a threshold filter that makes a binary `gray` Mat array based on the threshold applied to the array `gray0` according to the level. If the condition is true, the array contains white pixel at that location else black pixel

A more generic detection code based on the grayscale image would work better like this:

```
Mat binary_img(color_img.size(),CV_8UC1);
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<cv::Point> approx;
cv::GaussianBlur(color_img, color_img, cv::Size(9,9), 3);
cv::medianBlur(color_img, color_img, 9);
cv::medianBlur(color_img, color_img, 9);
cvtColor(color_img,binary_img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
IplImage tempBinary=IplImage(binary_img);
cvInRangeS(&tempBinary, Scalar(20), Scalar(100), &tempBinary);
Mat imgMat=Mat(&tempBinary);
findContours( imgMat, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.0005, true);
    if(approx.size()==4)
       //draw approx
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second half of the line, `gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N`, is a condition. `gray` is a variable, which will contain the truth-fullness of this condition, thus it will be a boolean. But it is c/c++ code, and the booleans are integers here.

About this condition:

(l+1)*255/N will move the interval (1,l) to (0,255). Thus, for l=0 it will be 255/N. For l=N it will be exactly 255.

Comment: They may not be bools if they are classes with overloaded operators.

Comment: @NeilKirk Of course it can't be an 100% exact explanation, but this is also not which from the OP asked for.

Comment: He didn't format all the code properly, but they are type Mat which I assume is opencv class of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the value of `l+1` (1 added to make the range started from 1 to 256, instead of 0 to 255) multiplied by 255 and integer divided by N being less than or equal to threshold value `gray0`, gray is set to 0 or 1 (pure black or pure white)

`gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;`